# How do I keep the 'hover' effect while using a Jquery color change effect while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create the effect of a navigation bar having its text change color on scroll. the problem is that once you start scrolling, the hover effect done with css does not work anymore. 
Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scroll_pos = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_pos > 600) {

      $(".normalmenuitem").css('color', '#a9a9a9');
    } else {

      $(".normalmenuitem").css('color', '#5f666f');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 4000px;
}
.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 59px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.navigationmenu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#logo {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  left: 17px;
  width: 160px;
}
/* top right menu! */

.holderrr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0px;
}
.rightmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sourcesanspro-semibold;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 17px 6px 17px;
}
.normalmenuitem {
  padding: 6px 17px 6px 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5f666f;
  transition: .3s color;
}
.normalmenuitem:hover {
  color: #292f36;
}
#trial {
  color: #e16065;
}
#trial:hover {
  color: #d64f54;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigationmenu">

  <div class="box"></div>

  <div class="nav">
    <a href="http://braemo.com">
      <img id='logo' src="http://images8.webydo.com/92/9273203/3958%2f4F9144FD-A273-B76D-94C9-3D8B569C8993.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="holderrr">
    <div class="rightmenu">
      <a class="normalmenuitem" href='http://braemo.com/support.html'>Features</a>
      <a class="normalmenuitem" href='http://braemo.com/support.html'>Pricing</a>
      <a class="normalmenuitem" href='http://braemo.com/support.html'>Stories</a>
      <a class="normalmenuitem" href='http://braemo.com/support.html'>Blog</a>
      <a class="normalmenuitem" href='http://braemo.com/support.html'>Language</a>
      <a class="normalmenuitem" href='http://braemo.com/support.html'>Support</a>
      <a class="normalmenuitem" href='http://dashboard.braemo.com'>Log In</a>
      <a class="rightmenu" id="trial" href='http://braemo.com/pricing.html'>Start Free Trial</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to scroll while at the same time hovering at text, do i understand that correctly?

Comment: you need this behaviour? https://jsfiddle.net/z7je0vn6/

Comment: the only problem i saw was that navbar was not fixed top

Comment: @Zoheiry lets reformulate: I used Jquery to make a text color change effect, when scrolling down 600px the color changes to a lighter grey, as you see. But the hover effect made in css no longer works

Comment: @CvEijk If my answer works for you, I would really appreciate getting a correct answer check, Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that Jquery overrides the CSS, if you want your CSS to override Jquery again you have to use `!important` for example:

```
.normalmenuitem:hover {
  color: #292f36 !important;
}
```

Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/jL2z8yy4/

Comment: Thanks! This Worked!